# How to expand yasnippet snippet inside html file

Tags: emacs, elisp, yasnippet

I have a lisp script that creates an empty html file:

```
(let ((mode "html-mode"))

  (funcall (intern mode)))

(write-region "" nil "index.html")
```

Then i'm using yasnippet to generate the basic html file: 
I have a snippet named "base" (i hit TAB key to expand it)

Is there a way to use this snippet in my lisp script?

i try, with no succes to use (yas/expand-snippet base)

Thanks.

Goulven.

**EDIT**

Using the code of abo-abo, I got something that works well:

```
(defun create-web-site-test()
  (interactive)
  (setq msg (concatenate 'string "Create web site in : " default-directory))
  (if (y-or-n-p msg)
    (progn  
     (write-region "" nil "./index.html")
     (find-file "./index.html")
     (html-mode)    
     (insert "\nbase")
     (yas/expand)
     (save-buffer)
     (kill-buffer))
    (progn
      ;; Give up
      (message "Ok, nothing will be donne, bybye...")
      )))
```

I just need to set the current directory to the right place using Mx cd.
There is probably a more effective solution, without opening the file in a buffer. But this one is already pretty cool.
Thanks abo-abo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
(progn
  (html-mode)
  (insert-file-contents "~/index.html")
  (insert "\nbase")
  (yas/expand))
```

And please do try to read the elisp manual.
It's very good.

### UPD

I've updated the function. I see that you're new.
To get a good answer you need to state clearly what you
want to do. And if this answer is useful, don't forget
to up-vote and accept.

Also, some comments on your code: `concat` should be used
for strings, instead of `concatenate`. And it's best not
to use `y-or-n-p` - just do what you want to do, and
if you want to abort, use <kbd>C-g</kbd>.

```
(defun create-test (directory)
  (interactive "D")
  (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect 
                        (concat directory "index.html"))
    (delete-region (point-min) (point-max))
    (html-mode)
    (insert "base")
    (yas/expand)
    (save-buffer)
    (kill-buffer)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer abo-abo. I thinks it will help me to do what i want.
Your code doesn't work perfectly because the snippet is expand in the scratch buffer, not in the index.html file. I will look in the Emacs Lisp  Manual how to manipulate corectly the file and the buffers.

Comment: I will remember your advice, sorry for the lack of clarity. I look at your code as soon as possible.
Thank you again.

Comment: In fact, I used y-or-n-p because i did not find a way to navigate my file system to choose a folder. Also thank you for this!!!!